# Key mismatch on column with value 0

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

Firt of all, thank you for using your time and reading my question.

Secondly, I would like to receive some help from you to fix a relational error with two entities in loopback.

The error I'm facing is the next one;

Key mismatch: OpsItinerary.itinerary_status_ind: 0, GenIndicatorValue.ind_value: 0

For some reasons, loopback cannot create a relation since the source and target value starts with 0, the identity value should be greater than that. I have some other relations with this target entity with values like 1 or 2 and the api performs exactly as I expect.

Is there any workaround to show the results expected since the relation is tested with another values (greater than 0) and it's working fine?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug. Please file an issue at https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues

Comment: I posted the same question in loopback github issues, hope they answer soon... Here's the link in case anyone would like to keep track of it, https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/967